# What are the first tasks for implementing Unit Testing in Brownfield Applications?

Tags: sql, language-agnostic, programming-languages, testing-strategies

Do you refactor your SQL first? Your architecture? or your code base?
Do you change languages? Do you throw everything away and start from scratch? [Not refactoring]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm adding unit testing to a large, legacy spaghetti codebase.

My approach is, when asked to solve a problem, I try to create a new wrapper around the part of the code-base which is relevant to my current task. This new wrapper is developed using TTD (writing the test first). Some of the time calling *into* the non-unit tested legacy code. At other times I make a new copy of an existing module and start to do serious violence to it. Sometimes I rewrite functionality from scratch.

But as I'm keeping it fairly well tested I feel pretty in control.

What I find with this code-base, which has been developed with far too much copy and pasting, is that once I get an understanding a particular part, and extract some functions from it (which are done test-first) ... these functions often turn out to be usable in many other places and so the rate of replacing the legacy code with my own, unit tested libraries increases.

I don't (and have no authority to) try to rewrite or add tests to parts of the code that are not touched by my current problem (usually a bug I'm trying to fix) but I do have a fairly aggressive proactive stance on anything that is touched and might be relevant.

Update : Penguinix asked : "What languages do you work in? Is there a specific Testing Harness you recommend?"

Right now I'm working in ... er ... Mumps! But the same principle works anywhere.

Something that transformed my understanding of UT was MinUnit : http://www.jera.com/techinfo/jtns/jtn002.html

When I saw MinUnit, that was kind of a "zen" moment of enlightenment for me. It stripped away the misunderstandings I had about unit testing being something complicated requiring sophisticated OO frameworks etc. I understood that UT was just about writing a bunch of tests. The "harness" you can write yourself, in about 3 minutes, in any language you like. Just get on and do it.

Comment: What languages do you work in? Is there a specific Testing Harness you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the state of the codebase... are there massive classes? one class with mega-methods? Are the classes tightly coupled? is configuration a burden?

Considering this, I suggest reading [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052), picking out your problems, and applying the recommendations.

Comment: Looks interesting. I'm using 'Working Effectively...' right now on my first major brownfield application and it's helping a lot. I think Refactoring http://www.amazon.com/dp/0201485672 may also be useful (my next purchase).

Comment: Refactoring by Martin Fowler is a refactor-er's bible. It has been very helpful in my development. I also recommend Head First Design Patterns, and Code Complete.